# How to sum filed based on day type in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

The table has two columns named dayType and total, total column already has value and only want to sum records that have the same dayType.

I coded this

```
 if{EB_Tam_DailyMv.dmv_daytype}= "R" then 
 sum({EB_Tam_DailyMv.dmv_totalot})

 else if {EB_Tam_DailyMv.dmv_daytype} = "P" then 
 sum ({EB_Tam_DailyMv.dmv_totalot})
```

it suppose to print the total of R days but it cannot work or my logic is not right ...

Advance thanks for help

Comment: Where did you place the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same field  {EB_Tam_DailyMv.dmv_totalot} in the case the days are "R" type both the days are "P" type, so when you use "sum" formula crystal report add all field {EB_Tam_DailyMv.dmv_totalot} of the report regardless of the type of day.

if you want to create a sum of all "P" days and separately the sum of "R" days you have to create 2 different formula like this:

formula1: SumOfP

```
if uppercase({EB_Tam_DailyMv.dmv_daytype}) = "P" then 
{EB_Tam_DailyMv.dmv_totalot} else 0
```

formula2: SumOfR

```
if uppercase({EB_Tam_DailyMv.dmv_daytype}) = "R" then 
{EB_Tam_DailyMv.dmv_totalot} else 0
```

and put them in your report(if you want you can hide them), 
then create two "running total fields", one that sum SumOfP formula and one that sum SumOfR formula.

Comment: How to sum using running tools?

Comment: Under field explorer menù select "running total fields" -> right click-> new

Comment: or you can create two summary by click on "insert" menu -> "Summary" and then insert the name of your formula